# How to save contents of dynamically generated forms on back/forward?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I'm currently writing a tool that allows a user to specify a complicated set of data through dynamic inputs. It's possible to pre-populate the tool with inputs by using a GET query [such as main.html?inputs={...}]

Unfortunately, if you run the site normally [visit main.html], then submit the form and decide to go back to the previous page, all state is lost.

I can serialize the current inputs quite trivially, and something similar to the following would work, if it were valid.

```
   document.location.href = "main.html?input={...}";
   form.submitForm();
```

Is there a way to sent the current URL [for browser history's sake] and continue executing my code? Alternatively, is there a way to insert an additional entry in the history before navigating to the next page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the location's hash property (eg: main.html#someHashValue) to simulate page changes. It will alter the url, therefore allowing the user to use the normal back and forward buttons in the browser, but it won't cause a refresh.

All you have to do in javascript is check the hash value every second or so to see if it has changed. You can see an example of this technique on my website [MarshallBrekka.com](http://www.marshallbrekka.com/#!video)

Comment: I guess I was overthinking it! Serializing and putting on a hash has some issues (especially if you add the reload function on hashchange), but it seemed to work out mostly for the better.